# Java Hibernate - Transaction is not active while retriving values from data base

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I need to get some data from data base. for this i have written code like

```
try{
   return (EmployeeImpl) em.createQuery(
      "select e from EmployeeImpl e " +
      "where e.empName = :employeeName " + 
          " and (e.eDate is null or e.eDate <=   :todaysDate )")
 .setParameter("employeeName", employeeName)
 .setParameter("todaysDate", todaysDate)
 .getSingleResult();
}catch(NoResultException exception){
     throw new NoResultException("Record not found");
}
```

i should return one valid record. but gives exception like

org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0a5308fa:126a:4fb36c77:559 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0a5308fa:126a:4fb36c77:559 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >)

```
 org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
```

My application can connect to data base as i am able to perform CRUD operation at other places.

What could be the possible reason for this exception.

Comment: Can you post the entire method and if possible the configuration details on how you acquire the session and pass it on to this method

Answer (score 1):

**Root Cause : Unavailability of data**

getSingleResult() throws null pointer exception whereas getResultList() returns null, is case of zero records are found against the criteria you pass in your query. 
try replacing:-

```
catch(NoResultException exception){
     throw new NoResultException("Record not found");
}
```

with

```
catch(NoResultException exception){
    throw new NoResultException("Record not found");
}
catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm sure you will get NullPointerException in logs. In Brief this complete trace one should get :-

```
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffa9b67064:126a:58924abe:14bb957 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffa9b67064:126a:58924abe:14bb957 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >)
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
```

Which clearly states how and why your transaction is being aborted.

Answer (score 0):

The reason seems clear:

> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection

For whatever reason, the code you posted is unable to acquire a connection while other parts of your application (according to what you've posted) are able to do so fine. I would check to make sure that this part of the code is not configured differently, using a different method for getting connections, etc.

Comment: i have already checked, configuration and other things are same.

Comment: does your database limit the number of connections per user? what does the full stacktrace look like?

Comment: database does not limit number of connections.

Answer (score 0):

Before actually carrying out any database operation such as insert, update or select, you should first start a transaction(after getting the session object of course). And then you should do any CRUD operation. Please make sure that you are starting a transaction before executing your query.